# VKB not showing up after portin LWUIT to Codename one

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I am trying to port my LWUIT app to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com)

I have a textField in my LWUIT app. On a touchscreen phone, whenever I clicked this textfield, a VKB would show up.

Now I have ported the LWUIT app to Codename one. Now, in the emulator whenever I click the textfield, the VKB is not showing up automatically.

Why is this happening and how do i fix it? I want the VKB to automatically show up on clicking the textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on the device.

In the simulator you can uncheck the menu option "Simulate->Native Input" to get that behavior.